# Print table caption in two lines R shiny

Tags: shiny

I need to print table caption in two lines as like this

```
My New table
New Statistics
```

My code is

```
output$table <-DT::renderDataTable({dataa <- dataa()},
                                caption = "My New table New Statistics",filter="top")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
caption = HTML("My New table <br/> New Statistics")
```